# Receive and handle dynamics 365 webhook

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, webhooks, asp.net-webhooks

I'm building this application that creates a webhook on dynamics CRM whenever a new  contact is created. I've been following this guide [Receiving WebHooks in your web application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2016/01/15/sending-webhooks-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm/) and [ASP.NET WebHooks - receiving and processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/). I'm using requestbin to check if the webhook is actually created, and it works. The webhook is created. Problem is, i dont understand how to receive the data in my windows form. 
I've added this into my App.config

```
<appSettings>
       <add key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_dynamicscrm" value="12345678901234567890123456789012"/>
</appSettings>
```

I've also created two classes:

- WebHookRegister: Registers the dynamics CRM webhook

  ```
  public static class WebHookRegister
  {
      public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
      {
          config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

          config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id= RouteParameter.Optional }
          );

          config.InitializeReceiveDynamicsCrmWebHooks();
      }
  }
  ```
- DynamicsWebHookHandler: Gets the data from the webhook ( for now im doing nothing with it, later i will use it do to stuff ).

  ```
  public class DynamicsWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
  {
      public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)
      {
           JObject data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();

           return Task.FromResult(true); 
      }
  }
  ```

Last thing i've done is register my webhook in the program ( right after my form is initialized, by calling this:

```
WebHookRegister.Register(new HttpConfiguration());
```

I know by reading the guide that the webhook receiver URI must be created as follows: `https://<host>/api/webhooks/incoming/<receiver>/{id}`, but I'm not understanding where to create it in the code.

Thanks for any help